# How to print high numbered unicode characters in python

Tags: python, windows, unicode

i am trying to write a python program that prints music notes (like  -> u1d15e). However, i cant quite get it to work.

Here is what i get using the following code

```py
note = '\U0001d15e'
bytes = note.encode('utf-8')
print(bytes)

>>> b'\xf0\x9d\x85\x9e'
```

If i try to print the string directly i get

```py
note = '\U0001d15e'
# bytes = note.encode('utf-8')
print(note)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\___\___\___\file.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(note)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001d15e' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am not sure what the problem is. I know that similar questions have been asked before, however the proposed solution did not work for me. Thank you for your help in advance :)

i am using python 3.10.4

Comment: When I run `print(note)` in IDLE I get a question mark which indicates that the font can't handle the code point, but I don't get any error.

Comment: The short version is that this is a Windows problem (more specifically, a `cmd.exe` problem) that doesn't really have anything to do with Python, and you may or may not be able to do anything about it, depending on the character.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the problem was my windows console was not set to utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My system doesn't like that representation either, but can directly put it into a string and `print()` it

To me, this is some artifact of your system being Windows and you need to set your console to use UTF-8 instead of [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

[Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window)

```py
>>> "" == "\U0001d15e"
True
>>> note = ""
>>> note.encode()
b'\xf0\x9d\x85\x9e'
>>> print(note)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. i changed my windows console to utf-8, now it works!